# Django - How to exclude instances in queryset due to foreign key model relation

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter out the instances in Quotation model if there are any item instances that are not within a certain list of items. The certain list of items are retrieved from the ProjectItem model. The model structure is below, I will explain more after the code.

models.py

```
class SalesProject(models.Model):
    sales_project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sales_project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProjectItem(models.Model):
    project_item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('SalesProject', related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remarks = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

class Quotation(models.Model):
    quotation_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    salesProject = models.ForeignKey(
        'SalesProject', related_name='quotations', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    details = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

class QuotationItem(models.Model):
    quotation_item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    quotation = models.ForeignKey('Quotation', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items', null=True, blank=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

class Item(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    item_description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

Firstly, I will get a list of Item instances by querying the current SalesProject. (where project = a SalesProject instance)

```
items = ProjectItem.objects.filter(project=project).values_list('item', flat=True)
```

Basically the Item instances that are within this items list are the 'permitted items' of sorts. What I would want to return is all the Quotation instances that contains only Item instances within this list (or to exclude any Quotation instances with Item instances outside of this list). The relation of Quotation to Item is through a QuotationItem model. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks all for the help, do guide me along, and let me know if there is insufficient information.

Comment: How exactly does the `Quotation` maps toa `ProjectItem`? At first sight the two are only connected through the `Porject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Quotation.objects.filter(items__item__projectitem__project=project)
```

You can make use of [**`.distinct()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to ensure you return each `Quotation` object only once:

```
Quotation.objects.filter(items__item__projectitem__project=project).distinct()
```

if you want `Quotation`s that *only* refer to the `project`, you can make use of `.exclude(…)`, or perhaps more straightforward, count the `Project`s:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Quotation.objects.annotate(
    nproject=Count('items__item__projectitem__project', distinct=True),
    nproject_project=Count(
        'items__item__projectitem__project',
        distinct=True,
        filter=Q(items__item__projectitem__project=project)
    ),
).filter(
    nproject_project=1,
    nproject=1
).distinct()
```

---

> **Note**: Your `QuotationItem` model basically acts like a *through* model of a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField),
> you might want to add a `ManyToManyField` with this model as [**`through=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).
> This makes querying such relations with the Django ORM more convenient.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But can I check, how did you get projectitem within the filter query? Is it a default reverse name to use? (the relation from Item to ProjectItem)

Comment: @jason: yes, if you do not specify a `related_query_name`, it will take the `related_name`, and if that is missing as well, it will take the model name in *lowercase*.

Comment: okay thank you, I will look into changing it to a ManyToMany field with a through model as well. Can I also check, if it would be possible for the entire Quotation instance to not be filtered out if there is even 1 QuotationItem instance that has a foreign key relation to an Item instance not within the Project? (through ProjectItem)

Comment: @jason: that is the case. It will retain the `Quotation` if there is at least one `QuotationItem` with one `Item` with one `PorjectItem` that has as project `Project`. So it is *existentially* quantified.

Comment: for example, if Quotation id:1 has 2 QuotationItem instances, 1 with foreign key to Item id: 1, and the other to Item id: 2. And SalesProject id:1 has 1 ProjectItem instance, with foreign key to Item id:1, the entire Quotation id: 1 would not be included in the filtered queryset as it contains a QuotationItem with foreign key to Item id: 2, which is not part of the Project (since SalesProject only contains 1 ProjectItem instance which links to only Item id:1 , not Item id: 2) sorry if I did not explain properly, but do let me know if it is possible to do so, thanks!

Comment: @jason: normally it should still be *in* the queryset. In order to *exclude* it, one should negate the condition and use `.exclude(..)`, so here the `Quotation` would normally still be *in* the queryset. But I think it is better to test this.

Comment: If I were to want to exclude it, how would I go about to achieve that? Sorry I am relatively new to Django

Comment: @jason: normally with `Quotation.objects.exclude(~Q(items__item__projectitem__project=project)).filter(items__item__projectitem__project=project)` (where you import `Q` with `from django.db.models import Q`).

Comment: oh thanks! Can I check what the ~ in front of Q does?

Comment: @jason: it is the *negation* of the condition, so we want to exclude all the objects that do *not* refer to project.

Comment: oh I see, thank you so much! I did not know that there was a ~ available to negate conditions, thank you!

Comment: sorry, can I check what is the use of filtering after the exclude? Wouldn't the exclude be enough to return the necessary stuff? Or is that second filter to ensure the Quotations without any Items linked to it wont be returned?

Comment: @jason: well not per se, since it is for example possible that there is no `QuotationItem` at all, in that case the exclude will not exclude that.

Comment: oh okay I see, thank you, you're a lifesaver haha :-)

Comment: @jason: you can also work with aggregates, see edit.